# sparse matrix - sparse matrix multiplication algo. performance improvement in R

Tags: r, openmp, sparse-matrix, rcpp, armadillo

My mac's R is linked with openblas. When I look at the "% CPU" usage while performing the *sparse-sparse multiplication in R or in Rcpp using Armadillo*, it doesn't seem like multithreading is being used unlike the dense-dense multiplication. Speed-wise, the single thread sparse-sparse multiplication in R or Armadillo seems slower than Matlab as well.

To address this issue, I have implemented FG Gustavson's algorithm (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355796) for performing sparse-sparse matrix multiplication in Rcpp using Armadillo's spMat container.

I can see an improvement (please see below) if I ignore ordering of the rows which is direct implementation of the algorithm, however the standard ordering makes it slower than R's (*edited as per mtall's comment*). I am not an expert in Rcpp/RcppArmadillo/C++ and I am looking for help in two specific things:

- Programmatically how can I make the **sp_sp_gc_ord** function more efficient and faster based on single thread application?
- My lame attempt at multithreading **sp_sp_gc_ord** with **openmp** is causing R to crash. I have commented out the *omp* commands below. I have looked at Rcpp gallery discussions on OpenMP http://gallery.rcpp.org/tags/openmp/ but couldn't figure out the problem

I would appreciate any help. Below here is a reproducible example of the code and corresponding microbenchmark:

```
#### Rcpp functions

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
sp_mat sp_sp_gc_ord(const arma::sp_mat &A, const arma::sp_mat &B, double p){

  // This function evaluates A * B where both A & B are sparse and the resultant
  // product is also sparse

  // define matrix sizes
  const int mA= A.n_rows;
  const int nB= B.n_cols;

  // number of non-zeros in the resultant matrix
  const int nnzC = ceil(mA * nB * p);

  // initialize colptr, row_index and value vectors for the resultant sparse matrix
  urowvec colptrC(nB+1);
  colptrC.zeros();
  uvec rowvalC(nnzC);
  rowvalC.zeros();
  colvec nzvalC(nnzC);

  //setenv("OMP_STACKSIZE","500M",1);

  // counters and other variables
  unsigned int i, jp, j, kp, k, vp; 
  unsigned int ip = 0;
  double nzB, nzA; 
  ivec xb(mA);
  xb.fill(-1);
  vec x(mA);

  // loop logic: outer loop over columns of B and inner loop over columns of A and then aggregate

  //  #pragma omp parallel for shared(colptrC,rowvalC,nzvalC,x,xb,ip,A,B) private(j,nzA,nzB,kp,i,jp,kp,k,vp) default(none) schedule(auto) 
  for(i=0; i< nB; i++) { 

    colptrC.at(i) = ip;

    for ( jp = B.col_ptrs[i]; jp < B.col_ptrs[i+1]; jp++) {

      j = B.row_indices[jp];
      nzB = B.values[jp];

      for ( kp = A.col_ptrs[j]; kp < A.col_ptrs[j+1]; kp++ ){

        k = A.row_indices[kp];
        nzA = A.values[kp];

        if (xb.at(k) != i){
          rowvalC.at(ip) = k;
          ip +=1;
          // Rcpp::print(wrap(ip));
          xb.at(k) = i;
          x.at(k) = nzA * nzB;
        } else {
          x.at(k) += nzA * nzB;
        }
      }
    }

    // put in the value vector of resultant matrix

    if(ip>0){        
      for ( vp= colptrC.at(i); vp <= (ip-1); vp++ ) {
        nzvalC.at(vp) = x(rowvalC.at(vp));
      }

    }
  }

  // resize and put in the spMat container
  colptrC.at(nB) = ip;
  sp_mat C(rowvalC.subvec(0,(ip-1)),colptrC,nzvalC.subvec(0,(ip-1)),mA,nB);

  // Gustavson's algorithm produces unordered rows for each column: a standard way to address this is: (X.t()).t()

  return (C.t()).t();
}  


 // [[Rcpp::export]]
sp_mat sp_sp_arma(const sp_mat &A, const sp_mat &B){

  return A * B; 

} 


// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat dense_dense_arma(const mat &A, const mat &B){

  return A * B; 

} 

#### End
```

The corresponding microbenchmark part in R:

```
#### Microbenchmark 

library(Matrix)
library(microbenchmark) 

## define two matrices
m<- 1000
n<- 6000
p<- 2000

A<-  matrix(runif(m*n),m,n)
B<-  matrix(runif(n*p),n,p)
A[abs(A)> .01] = B[abs(B)> .01] = 0
A <- as(A,'dgCMatrix')
B<- as(B,'dgCMatrix')
Adense<- as.matrix(A)
Bdense<- as.matrix(B)

## sp_sp_gc is the function without ordering 

microbenchmark(sp_sp_gc(A,B,.5),sp_sp_arma(A,B),A%*%B,
dense_dense_arma(Adense,Bdense),Adense %*% Bdense,Adense %*% B, times=100)

Unit: milliseconds
                             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
              sp_sp_gc(A, B, 0.5)  16.09809  21.75001  25.76436  24.44657  26.96300  99.30778   100
          sp_sp_gc_ord(A, B, 0.5)  36.78781  44.64558  49.82102  47.64348  51.87361 116.85013   100
                 sp_sp_arma(A, B)  47.45203  52.77132  59.37077  59.24010  62.41710  86.15647   100
                          A %*% B  23.64307  28.99649  32.88566  32.10017  35.21816  59.16251   100
 dense_dense_arma(Adense, Bdense) 286.22358 302.95170 345.66766 317.75786 340.50143 862.15116   100
                Adense %*% Bdense 292.32099 317.10795 342.48345 329.80950 342.21333 697.56468   100
                     Adense %*% B 167.87248 186.63499 219.11872 195.19197 212.50286 843.17172   100   
####
```

sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.3/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.3.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-14           RcppArmadillo_0.8.500.0 Rcpp_0.12.18           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1  grid_3.5.1      lattice_0.20-35
```

Rcpp and RcppArmadillo are installed from source after installing clang4 for mac following coatless's link https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-rtools

Comment: This line `A[abs(A)> .01] = B[abs(B)> .01] = 0` will set A and B equal to each other

Comment: @HongOoi It didn't on my machine; try `all.equal(A, B)` immediately after `A[abs(A)> .01] = B[abs(B)> .01] = 0`. OP: I'm assuming that what's sometimes referred to as `A1` or `B1` up there is actually `Adense` and `Bdense`?

Comment: My bad, but it won't do what the OP thinks it does either

Comment: Sorry.  Setup on macOS appears to require sacrificing a goat or two every couple of months. Over here on Linux this stuff _just works_ and has for years.  I would suggest you follow i) the r-sig-mac list, ii) the recommendations by @coatless and iii) look closely at the package.  There is entire block in `configure.ac` just to figure this out on the mac.  So look closely at what `configure` says.

Comment: @duckmayr: Sorry, you are right. A1, B1 are nothing but Adense, Bdense. I initially named them as A1,B1 but then changed the names for better readability. Since it was there in GE, didn't see any error and got overlooked. Edited that part.

Comment: @Ghosh It looks like Gustavson's algorithm (in its original guise) produces `C` with unordered elements in each row. A direct translation of the algorithm to Compressed Sparse Column (CSC) format would produce unordered elements in each column. It seems that Armadillo is strictly using the ordered form of CSC. So your code would run faster, but produce the "wrong" result.

Comment: @mtall: Correct! I have added an approach to get ordered version but obviously that makes it slower. Please suggest any edits that you find faster. One thing I notice is Armadillo spMat internally accepts both variation but calling back to R GE     requires ordering.

Comment: @Ghosh Maybe modify the original Armadillo source code. It looks like it uses 2 passes. The first pass estimates the maximum number of nonzeros in the resulting matrix, and the second pass does the actual multiplication. Replacing the first pass with a rougher estimate might work.

Comment: @mtall: Thank you!  Armadillo spMat mult. seemed a bit slower than Matrix's for this example. Did you mean Matrix package's mult. source code? Anyway, I couldn't locate any of them. Could you point me to these source codes? Although my version is slower now, if you look at my code, you will see it to be one pass with an estimation parameter.  Generally, is there any obvious improvements that you can see here?

Comment: @Ghosh Is the transpose trick reliable? It would depend the armadillo sparse transpose function not being sensitive to ordering. It would be prudent to check that. The source code repository for armadillo (containing the latest version) seems to be on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code).  The code for sparse matrix multiply is in `include/armadillo_bits/spglue_times_meat.hpp`, and for sparse transpose is in `include/armadillo_bits/spop_strans_meat.hpp`.

Comment: @mtall: Yes. The transpose trick has been mentioned in few literatures. I finally ended up writing a Rcpp version of an adaption of Gustavson's algorithm found [here](https://www.geosci-model-dev-discuss.net/gmd-2016-204/). I don't see the ordering problem although R seems to not like it when the function return is being outputted. The openmp problem is also temporarily resolved for my mac. I have uploaded this in my [github](https://github.com/subhomoyghosh/sparse-matrix-multiplication-in-RcppArmadillo) repo.